# pandas dataframe find text from one column in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is what I have

```
df1:
    name
----------------
0  dog  
1  cat
2  chicken

df2
   name
---------
0  dog-collie
1  cat
2  chicken
```

what I'm trying to get is that compare first df1['name'] with df2['name'] to filter dog-collie

the result

```
df1
   name
-----------
0  cat
1  chicken
```

I could compare both column and add an extra column with 'True' or 'False' after comparison,like this

```
df1['result']=df1['name']==df2['name']
df1=df1['result']==True
```

but I wonder if there is any other way to do this (possibly a faster way, since there are a lot of rows)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this easily by using the [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) method to compute the intersection of `df1.name` and `df2.name`.

```py
result = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on='name')
# result is a DataFrame containing only the matching names from the original dataframes
```

I'm not sure about the implementation details of `merge`, but I imagine it has either similar or better efficiency than your solution.